# Arduino sprintf (for TX) and scanf (for RX) , why do I get strange output?

Tags: arduino, printf, scanf

I would like to know what I have wrong in my code.
Or is it actually correct?

Currently I have 4 code holding variables namely:

- hDroid (0 to 4 digits)
- pDroid (0 to 2 digits)
- ooDroid (0 to 3 digits)
- devDroid (0 to 4 digits)

Which I feed into in a character array (allcode) and then transmit that to the receiving side where they arrive (hopefully in same format?).

The problem is that the output has extra characters and I can't figure out why. Is it just the Arduino Serial Monitor?

Perhaps I am not setting the null character or not allocating enough memory in each or all the arrays.

I have put all into the same sketch in order to test `sprintf` and `scanf` perhaps this is the problem.

Desired is:

- Send: `1234,12,123,1234`
- Receive: `1234,12,123,1234`

My code is:

```cpp
//declare "code-holding" vars for send
char hDroid[5] = {
    "1234" }; //4 or less digits/keys eg 1234 + NULL
char pDroid[3] = {
    "21" }; //2 digits/keys eg 12 + NULL
char ooDroid[4] = {
    "123" }; //3 or less digits/keys eg 123 + NULL
char devDroid[5] = {
    "1234" }; //4 or less digits/keys eg 9999 + NULL 
char allDroid[18] = {
    '\0' }; //total array count including NULL's


//declare "code-holding" vars for receive
char hDroid1[5] = {
    '\0' }; //4 or less digits/keys eg 1234 + NULL
char pDroid1[3] = {
    '\0' }; //2 digits/keys eg 12 + NULL
char ooDroid1[4] = {
    '\0' }; //3 or less digits/keys eg 123 + NULL       
char devDroid1[5] = {
    '\0' }; //4 or less digits/keys eg 9999 + NULL 


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    sprintf(allDroid, "%s,%s,%s,%s", hDroid, pDroid, ooDroid, devDroid);
    Serial.println("This is allDroid "); //show content of allDroid 
    Serial.println(allDroid); //show content of allDroid
    delay(1000);
    sscanf(allDroid, "%s,%s,%s,%s", &hDroid1, &pDroid1, &ooDroid1, &devDroid1); // Converts a string to an array

    Serial.println("this is hDroid1,pDroid1,ooDroid1,devDroid1 "); //show content of allDroid

    Serial.println(hDroid1);

    Serial.println(pDroid1);

    Serial.println(ooDroid1);

    Serial.println(devDroid1);

    //clear the arrays
    memset(allDroid, 0, sizeof(allDroid));// This line is for reset the StringReceived
    memset(hDroid1, 0, sizeof(hDroid1));// This line is for reset the StringReceived
    memset(pDroid1, 0, sizeof(pDroid1));// This line is for reset the StringReceived
    memset(ooDroid1, 0, sizeof(ooDroid1));// This line is for reset the StringReceived
    memset(devDroid1, 0, sizeof(devDroid1));// This line is for reset the StringReceived
}
```

And the output is:

```
This is allDroid 
1234,21,123,1234
this is hDroid1,pDroid1,ooDroid1,devDroid1 
1234,21,123,1234
21,123,1234
123,1234
1234
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @Hey24sheep its in the middle of the question

Comment: I read it but I am still unable to understand what you actually want to do.

Comment: I was getting junk code in the terminal window and it's been driving me dotty as to why ...:-( so I need some guru eyes to just check I have all code correct.

Comment: @Hey24sheep .. thanks a million for the reply .. what's not clear exactly ?

Comment: I got your point. You are getting garbage values along with your actual data. I am at office so no arduino here to play with your code :D. But your code looks fine to me. garbage value comes sometimes because of wrong baud rate as well. So maybe you should try that as well.

Comment: @Hey24sheep .. Thanks again for the feedback .. baud rates and start stop etc settings all checked .. so strange this cos in the 1.0.5 version I get the garbage charactes in output but using 1.6.5 alls good , Will try Putty a little later ..also had killer day at work.Will feedback and still hoping for sanity check'from some kind soul

Comment: You are welcome, I wasn't helpful though. It seems like that old 1.0.5 version is just have some buggy code whereas latest one is working fine. I would say its just the problem with Serial Monitor of old version.

Comment: @Hey24sheep .. did you check the array values ? do they seem correct ?

Comment: Yea, they are correct. I remember this same kind of thing happened to me when I was using hc-06 module. I was getting all garbage values. There was no solution for it but after a few months or so I upgraded my ide and it was normal. So may be same is happening with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got time today. I ran your code and its working perfectly fine. Here is my output. I am using the latest Arduino IDE and my board is Arduino Nano.

I think garbage values are because of old ide serial monitor. Just use the upgraded IDE.

[image]

Comment: Hey24sheep Thanks a million for confirmation and sanity check ! :-) I agree with you , must have been old Arduino Serial monitor

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is only when using the serial monitor on arduino IDE 1.0.5-r2, I tried the same code on Arduino IDE version 1.6.5 and the 'strange characters are gone from the output window !

    `This is allDroid 
    1234,21,123,1234
    this is hDroid1,pDroid1,ooDroid1,devDroid1 
    1234,21,123,1234`

As a sanity check could some kind soul please just check my code for correctness in terms of the arrays and their dimensions and Null terminations ?